# What is difference between outsourcing & delegation?

Tags: differences, synonyms

i was writing an article about [cad drafting services](https://www.gsourcedata.com/services/cad-drafting-services), could you let me know which one will be appropriate to use outsource or delegate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the major difference in what these two words connote is that delegation bestows authority or power, and outsourcing distributes work.

For example a constitution might delegate powers to Congress, a federal government might delegate powers to state or local governments, or to independent agencies like the Federal Communications Commission, like when they made the decisions on net neutrality which would affect what rules internet service providers would have to follow. Or the rights that a state road and traffic authority has to make road laws.

Outsourcing is when businesses or companies offload particular jobs or
grant contracts to other companies to do some work for them.

> In business, outsourcing is "an agreement in which one company
>   contracts-out a part of existing internal activity to another
>   company".
> [Outsourcing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outsourcing)

For example, if you run a clothing retail chain, the textiles might be made in one country, the shirts in another country, and then shipped to the country where the retail business operates.

However, in a loose way you could use delegate to mean outsourcing, but there is a distinction between the two.

If you're talking about contracting with someone else for CAD services, I would definitely call this outsourcing.

Comment: Outsourcing is correct as far as I'm concerned. You _delegate_ a task to someone in your own organisation who is subordinate to you. If you pay a contractor to do it you _outsource_ or _contract out_ or, if you are a contractor yourself, you _sub-contract_.